# How to make "this" reference a memory addres of an object in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, this

My problem is that I am trying to refefence a memory address of an object that is in a vector.

```
void Entity::align(std::vector <Entity> boids)
{
avg.mult(0);
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < boids.size(); i++)
{
    distance = this->position.dist(boids[i].position);

    if (&boids[i] == this);
    {
        avg.add(boids[i].velocity);
        total++;
    }
}

    if (total > 0)
    {
        avg.div(total);
    }
}
```

When debugging the code I found out that the first element of the vector and "this" have the same x and y parameters, so that they are in fact the same, but "this" gives back a different memory addres than the first element of the array. Why is that?

Comment: `boids` is passed by value, so a copy is made.  Try `void Entity::align(const std::vector <Entity>& boids)`.

Comment: And even after fixing the code so it passes the vector by reference, pedantically only `std::equal_to`, and friends, implement portable support for total order of pointer values, so one should use it to effect the pointer comparison.

Comment: @PaulSanders that worked and now the memory adresses are indeed the same but for whatever reason the if statement is executed for every object, even though the memory adresses are not the same. Would you know why that happens?

Comment: @DamianKowalski `if (&boids[i] == this);` - remove trailing semi-colon.

Comment: @PaulSanders that should be an answer.

Comment: @Fureeish Yeah, maybe, but it seemed too simple and of no long-term value to the site.

Comment: @PaulSanders maybe - imo that's an issue worth discussing on meta whether questions like that are of value to the site. On one hand, a simple fix (adding `&` or `const&`) does the job so one can say that it's too minor (I can even see a vote to close with the given reason being a *typo*). But I do not believe so - it's a question about a specific behaviour and a specific feature that ensures such behaviour. The fact that the feature is sometimes just 1 character more does not mean it should be compared to a typo...

Comment: *"the first element of the vector and 'this' have the same x and y parameters, so that they are in fact the same"* -- there probably should be some more explanation for why you think this is true. Having the same data typically makes objects *equal*, not necessarily the same. Two objects would be the same if their addresses are equal, and in your case they are not.

Answer (score 0):

> How to make “this” reference a memory addres of an object in a vector

By calling a non-static member function on that object. Example:

```
struct Entity {
    void foo() {
        // this points to the object argument
    }
};

boids[i].foo(); // within this function this points to object in vector
```

> I found out that the first element of the vector and "this" have the same x and y parameters, so that they are in fact the same

You haven't shown what x and y "parameters" are, but I assume they are members of the class. Having same values in member variables does not imply that two values refer to the same object. Example:

```
struct Entity {
    int xy;
};

Entity a {1};
Entity b {1};
```

Here, we have `a` and `b` which have the same value in members, but are nevertheless distinct objects.

> "this" gives back a different memory addres than the first element of the array. Why is that?

Because they are different objects.